# uWSGI snmp stats

Tags: django, snmp, uwsgi, cacti

I'm interested in collecting stats for uWSGI via snmp for graphing in Cacti.  Per [these docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/SNMP.html) I'm starting uwsgi with:

```
uwsgi -s :3031 --udp 192.168.10.1:2222 --snmp --snmp-community foo --emperor /usr/local/uwsgi/vassals --emperor-tyrant --pidfile /var/run/uwsgi.pid --vacuum
```

The example snmpget command they provided works fine:

```
$ snmpget -v2c -c foo 192.168.10.1:2222 1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.1.1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.35156.17.1.1 = Counter64: 0
```

however, I cannot see any other snmp "values" besides that one.  Shouldn't I be able to snmpwalk from the base OID?  When I try to see what values are exposed, I get a timeout.

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c foo 192.168.10.1:2222 1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17
Timeout: No Response from 192.168.10.1:2222
```

From the docs I referenced:

> General information is managed by the uWSGI server itself. The base
>   OID to access uWSGI SNMP information is 1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17
>   (iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprise.unbit.uwsgi). General options
>   are mapped to 1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.1.x.

I'm either not understanding snmp in general, or what uWSGI is providing snmp-wise.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "old" snmp stats export only values managed by the apps via the api.

The new api is this one:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Metrics.html

that expose values via snmp as 1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.3.x

in both cases you cannot walk but only get direct values

Comment: OK knowing that I cannot walk the values and that its expected is helpful.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone as I couldn't find these uwsgi OIDs anywhere; had to manually compare the metrics in the metrics folder with one OID at time:

- worker.X.requests        1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.3.X.1
- worker.X.delta_requests  1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.3.X.2
- worker.X.avg_response_time   1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.3.X.8
- worker.1.total_tx        1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.3.1.9
- worker.1.rss_size            1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.3.1.11
- worker.1.vsz_size            1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.3.1.12
- busy_workers         1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.5.3
- idle_workers         1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.5.4
- overloaded               1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.5.5
- total_requests           1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.1.1
- total_trasmited_data     1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.5.100
- rss_memory_total         1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.5.101
- vsz_memory_total         1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.5.102
- avg_response_time            1.3.6.1.4.1.35156.17.5.103

Comment: and found them now in the source code:
https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/e24fef1fab2a412dce6bd39b4444b2b5775d0d6d/core/metrics.c#L746